# pycharm adds extra tab inside parentheses

Tags: python, pycharm

I just recently upgraded to a newer pycharm 2023.3.3 and noticing that it started to put an extra tab inside the parentheses.
Consider

`x = 'orange`
`x.replace('r', 'o')`

I would expect to have `x.replace('r', 'o')` stay as-is. 
However, pycharm places extra tabs before 'r' and 'o', ie `x.replace(    'r',     'o')`

How do I disable this auto-indent?  I looked all over but could not find anything...

[image]

Comment: By default, it *certainly* doesn't do this, if only because it would completely go against PEP8 (and it's actually pretty good at helping you follow that). You should probably include a screenshot of what it looks like when you type it and what it looks like after you move away from the line, and PyCharm has changed it, because it's not clear. However, from what you're describing, it sounds like you changed some non-standard setting to have this side effect yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Grismar!    I uploaded a screenshot.    I am presently looking into the plugins I installed.   Maybe that has some effect.   All I did was just an update from 2023.3.2 to 2023.3.3.  Before it was not placing these tabs.   The extra tabs are purely visual.   They do not show up in the actual saved raw .py file

Comment: This does match your description, but the colouring suggests you definitely have a non-standard setup. Also, it would be good to have a bit more context. Is this a .py file, in a normal editor window? A full screenshot of the PyCharm window would probably save answering a lot of questions. Also, when do the tabs appear? When you hit enter at the end of the line? When you write the closing parenthesis? Or even sooner?

Comment: For the record, I updated my Pycharm just to test this, and I cannot repro. It looks like your inlay hints aren't showing up, but space is being reserved for them. Maybe check the font colors. If a theme got messed up and made the background the same color as the font color, that would explain this.

Comment: Thanks, @Carcigenicate and @Grismar!    I just went ahead and reverted back to an older version of PyCharm and all works now  as it should with all the plugins..     Later I will reinstall the most recent version and will layer the plugins one by one to see which one triggers such behavior.